# Simplification of eigenvalue calculation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a test yesterday I needed to compute the eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix full with elements. So there was no easy way to compute the eigenvalues other than writing them out. After searching the internet, however, I found  [Samuelson's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html) for calculating the characteristic polynomial. Now I was wondering if there are other ways to simplify the calculation. I saw that row/ column operations are not possible since these change the eigenvalues.

Comment: Do you have a description of Samuelson's formula? The link you have in your question doesn't have it. In general, computing the eigenvalues of some matrix $A$ is going to take some work. However, you can build the characteristic polynomial by just knowing the determinant of $A$, the trace of $A$, and the trace of $A^2$, as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891687/how-do-you-quickly-find-the-eigenvalues-of-this-matrix)

Comment: Ah, I thought the link I referred too was called the Samuelson's formula. But it shows a similar approach to your answer I guess. Thanks for the article.